# MSDTC and Windows Server 2008 Error

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2008-r2, msdtc

I have an application server and a DB server, both with Windows Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2008 R2, I have a C# application installed and 2 databases (my application was developed using Framework 2.0), I use TransactionScope for Insert, Update and Delete, everything is fine when I execute any of those operations in just 1 db  but the problem comes if I work with the 2 databases at the same time, I don't have this problem installing the application and the databases in the same Server. I already configured MSDTC in both servers but I can't solve this error, by the way, I have the firewall turned on, I don't know if this is causing me any conflict.

I hope you can help me.

Thank you so mucho and have a nice day/night.

PS: I appologize for my english.

Comment: MSDTC issues are almost always configuration issues -- either MSDTC itself or network (usually firewall).  This is a good troubleshooting guide: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561924.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 .  It's about BizTalk but most of the article applies to any application using MSDTC.  If you can post more specific details about the configuration and what you've tried then serverfault.com is probably a better fit to get an answer.

Comment: Hey, thank's for your answer, there was an option I was missing on MSDTC configuration and my problem was solved but now, those operations (insert, update, delete) with 2 DB are too slow, if I execute the operations in 1 DB, the problem does not happen. Do you know why this is happen?